# How to import Excel data into gridview

Tags: .net, powershell

I want to take 2 Excel columns and import the two columns into gridview.

Code so far:

```
function Out-Excel
{
  param($Path = "$env:temp\$(Get-Date -Format yyyyMMddHHmmss).csv")

  $input | Export-CSV -Path $Path -UseCulture -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation

  Invoke-Item -Path $Path
}

Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Out-Excel
```

Comment: I fail to see how that code has anything to do with the question.

Comment: This is the code to make the gridview

Comment: Sorry if this question is odd I just started writing powershell this week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not make a grid view, it generates a temporary CSV file, and then opens that in Excel. If you want to create a grid view of it you should pipe the data to Out-GridView.

Your question is in fact two questions it seems. First, how do you get data from Excel into PowerShell, and secondly how do you display data in a GridView?

First, do you really need data from Excel as an application, or do you need data that is stored in an Excel file (.XLS, .XLSX), or do you need data saved in a CSV file? If it is just stored in a CSV file you can easily import data from that directly into Powershell with the Import-CSV cmdlet. If it is in an Excel file I would strongly suggest getting the [Import-XLS](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/17bcabe7-322a-43d3-9a27-f3f96618c74b) script from the TechNet script gallery. It simplifies the whole process, and there is no reason to recreate a function that somebody already did an excellent job creating. If the data is just currently in Excel I would suggest saving it as a CSV and importing it directly into Powershell from there.

Once the data is in Powershell you can pipe things from your array or cmdlet/function to Out-Gridview directly, or if you only want certain parts of the data pipe it to Select, and then to Out-Gridview. Such as the following example that goes in line with your example above:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Select ID,ProcessName,MainWindowTitle | Out-GridView
```

Or, from an array:

```
$Array = Get-Process
$Array | Where-Object { $_.MainWindowTitle } | Select ID,ProcessName,MainWindowTitle | Out-GridView
```